# Importing custom options for products - magento 1.7.0.0

Tags: magento-1.7, import, custom-options, ce-1.7.0.0

I've seen a few similar threads that asked this question but they were either using an outdated version or did not exactly meet my needs. So I thought I'd ask here:

- **Does Magento allow importing of custom options for "simple products" ? (ver 1.7.0.0)**
- **If it doesn't, by default, is there an easy way to allow such functionality?**

<sup>**Note:** If neither of these are possible, I am also open to suggestions about extensions (free or not) that address this need.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into using Magmi? It has a lot of extra functionality for imports, one of their plugins may meet your needs, if it isn't already in Magmi.

[Magmi on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/)

[Documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Comment: This is what I ended up going with. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome, it has served me quite well.

Comment: Just a word of warning about Magmi and custom options. I just tried it to append an extra field onto the end of a custom options list and it ended up removing them all! Luckily I backed up the database first, but just... be careful.

Answer (score 5):

Magento's ImportExport module (not the dataflow one) allows you to import custom options.

You need the following fields:

- _custom_option_store
- _custom_option_type
- _custom_option_title
- _custom_option_is_required
- _custom_option_price
- _custom_option_sku
- _custom_option_max_characters
- _custom_option_sort_order
- _custom_option_file_extension
- _custom_option_image_size_x
- _custom_option_image_size_y
- _custom_option_row_title
- _custom_option_row_price
- _custom_option_row_sku
- _custom_option_row_sort

As found here: https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php#L232

Logic is implemented here: https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php#L670

Explanation of fields: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/exporting-custom-variants-and-options

Presentation of the Mage ImportExport module, maybe this gives you some insight in how it works: http://www.slideshare.net/MagentoImagine/magentos-imagine-ecommerce-conference-2011-using-the-new-import-module

I can't really find an example how to use it.

**EDIT**

After exporting a product with some custom options, here's an example:

[image: example export]

Comment: Do I get it right that this module doesn't have any GUI in Community Edition? All the instruction articles are related to Magento Go.

Comment: Magento go uses the same GUI as Magento CE.

Comment: I must be missing something: the only export with a changeable field mapping I see in CE 1.9 is the DataFlow one. And the last incomplete phrase of the answer is something I still feel like :)

Answer (score -1):

Have some extension you can choice:

- http://www.mlx-store.com/magento-extensions/import-export/export-import-custom-options-product-for-magento.html
- http://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-product-import-export.html

Answer (score -1):

If you follow the below link for importing products with custom options, it will be properly imported to magento catalog.

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Custom_Options

If you are importing product using .csv file, the file must be having the column format as follows:

> Name:Type:Is Required:sort number (where, sort number is an optional)
>
> Example: Size:drop_down:0

So the quick example for dropdown's custom option value is,

> Medium:fixed:5|Large:fixed:10

with `|` symbol you can add more row for an option.

**Note:** under `Itemprocessors` section, `Custom Options` must be chosen.